# org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.java is missed in PrimeFaces 5.1

Tags: jsf, primefaces

This [pom](https://github.com/torsten-liermann/ServiceToolFaces/blob/master/pom.xml) defines **3.4** as version of PrimeFaces  :

Then , in  [PrimeResourceHandlerWithCache.java](https://github.com/torsten-liermann/ServiceToolFaces/blob/master/src/main/java/biz/liermann/demo/servicetool/web/util/PrimeResourceHandlerWithCache.java) extends `org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler` which is not defined in my project even the version of PrimeFaces is   **5.1** .

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
    <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
    <version>5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

I inspect the pom mentioned above & the pom of my project , i note also a difference in repository :

My Project POM :

```
 <repository>
      <id>prime-repo</id>
      <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
      <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

However the other :

```
<repository>
    <id>primefaces</id>
    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
    <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

How to update my pom to get `org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler` defined?

Answer (score 0):

No more  :

**`org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler`**

But it becomes in :

**`org.primefaces.application.resource.PrimeResourceHandler`**

in 5 version